# Re push a directory to remote git after accidentally deleting it

Tags: git, github

I have my project on openshift. I commited and pushed some changes on my git remote host but accidentaly deleted them after ssh logging on the server. I tried to re-add them commit them and push them but when I commit it says that there is nothing to commit. I tried to force push but it says that everything is up to date. Is there a way to recommit something without reverting back?

```
git add path/to/my/directory/
git commit -m "Re commiting"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Tried this to

```
git push -f
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

In Git 2.0, Git will default to the more conservative 'simple'
behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

Everything up-to-date
```

How can I re-push my directory?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with *openshift* but I presume that there’s a git *post-receive*
hook on the server which checks out your master branch to a certain working
directory.

You should check the contents of this hook on the remote server (it should be
located at something like `~git/repositories/project.git/hooks/post-receive`).
More thank likely, it will contain a command similar to:

```
GIT_DIR=~git/repositories/project.git/ GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/vhosts/project  git checkout -f master
```

You should then run that command while logged in as the git user; running as
another user will lead to file permission problems.